# race dataset in R how to improve the predictions

Tags: r, prediction, generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset from 2002 to 2016 with information about the results of a road bike race. I am trying to predict the results after applying different models but the results are not great and I am trying to improve it.

My data set has the following information.

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   86812 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ year              : int  2008 2014 2009 2015 2016 2004 2011 2015 2011 2010 ...
 $ personal_id_number: Factor w/ 56596 levels "00027___hashed_values__74fab",..: 51224 24111 19719 55867 11953 42993 54332 44273 52824 25504 ...
 $ postalcode        : Factor w/ 5502 levels "","-5501","*1202",..: 3603 4728 4335 4728 2260 5061 1330 3302 1595 107 ...
 $ country           : Factor w/ 42 levels "ANDORRA","ARGENTINE",..: 35 15 35 15 35 35 15 35 35 35 ...
 $ county            : Factor w/ 263 levels "None",..: 218 35 252 35 151 33 66 10 106 6 ...
 $ town              : Factor w/ 3799 levels "","None",..: 1425 388 13 388 358 1530 650 172 638 3683 ...
 $ gender            : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ years_old_when_run: int  31 46 35 47 42 39 55 44 23 34 ...
 $ club              : Factor w/ 8201 levels " ","   ADAMUZ",..: 4681 4735 6211 4735 3565 6211 6211 6211 6211 6211 ...
 $ license           : Factor w/ 2 levels "False","True": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ insurance         : Factor w/ 2 levels "False","True": 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ finaltime         : int  566 586 489 433 719 514 433 494 489 462 ...
 $ temp              : num  32.6 30.8 21.3 24.6 14.4 18 16 24.6 16 13.9 ...
 $ wind_direction    : int  90 50 310 330 240 260 300 330 300 250 ...
 $ wind_speed        : num  4.1 3.1 4.6 2.2 4.6 7.2 7.2 2.2 7.2 4.6 ...
 $ pressure          : int  97440 97010 98180 97940 98310 97010 97780 97940 97780 97250 ...
 $ humidity          : int  38 35 48 49 78 65 70 49 70 82 ...
 $ TimesPreviouslyRun: int  0 1 0 0 6 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ Finishing         : Factor w/ 2 levels "False","True": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

After a descriptive analysis, I have created some factors for TimesPreviouslyRun, YearsOldWhenRun, Temp, Humidity, Pressure, JoinInClub, Dropout and Country

So, my formula used in different methods looks like:

```
log_formula  <- log_finaltime_train~gender+insurance+country_block+years_old_when_run_block+TimesPreviouslyRun_Block+wind_direction_block+temp_block+humidity_block+wind_speed_block+pressure_block+joinedinclub+dropout
```

I have tried some methods like nnet, glm, svm, and gbm but the predictions are not very good. An example could be:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 6, summaryFunction=defaultSummary)
Grid <- expand.grid( n.trees = seq(10,100,10), interaction.depth = c(30), n.minobsinnode=0.1, shrinkage = c(0.1))
fit.gbm <- train(log_formulaB, data=train, method = 'gbm', trControl=fitControl,tuneGrid=Grid,metric='RMSE',maximize=FALSE)
predict.gbm <- predict(fit.gbm, test,interval="predict")
```

I know that the dataset for this predicition is not the best one but its what I have.

I would like to know if will be possible to add in my analysis the following information: After reviewing the data I found out that the people usually need the same amount of time needed in previous years. I mean, if a person needed in 2008, 400 minutes, in 2010 this person needed around 400 minutes. On the other hand people who needed 700 minutes in 2004, also needed in 2005, 710 minutes. 
But I am not sure how to add this information in my formula or analysis. Any ideas about how to add this information or to improve my predictions?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming related question, and thus does not belong on StackOverflow. I think stats.stackexchange is a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: This is quite broad. Competitions are won over improving predictions.

Comment: can you share the dataset ?